# Using left join to query and match JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, left-join

Table A,field : pay_type_fk,type:json, Examples Data: [1,2,4]
Table B,field : id type : bigint Examples Data: primary key

SQL I use:

```
SELECT
    pay_payment_type.id,
    pay_payment_type.pay_name,
    pay_payment_type.configuration,
    pay_payment_type.pay_function_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT( pay_type.MODE ) 
FROM
    pay_payment_type
    LEFT JOIN pay_type ON pay_type.id = CAST( JSON_EXTRACT( pay_payment_type.pay_type_fk, '$[0]' ) AS UNSIGNED ) 
GROUP BY
    pay_payment_type.id
```

Only pay can be found_ For the first record in the type table, I think we can query all of them with group_ CONCAT

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can `join` on `JSON_CONTAINS()`:

```
select
    ppt.id,
    ppt.pay_name,
    ppt.configuration,
    ppt.pay_function_name,
    group_concat(pt.mode) as pay_type_modes 
from pay_payment_type ppt
left join pay_type pt on json_contains(ppt.pay_type_fk, cast(pt.id as char))
group by ppt.id
```

That said, a better option would be to fix your design. Instead of using a JSON array to store multiple dependent keys, you should have a separate bridge table to represent this many-to-many relationship, with each value in a separate row.

Comment: yes..there are problems in the design, but there are many implications. It's better not to modify them..thank you~~~~~

Comment: Invalid data type for JSON data in argument 1 to function json_contains; a JSON string or JSON type is required.

Comment: @l0s7r: your question stated that  `pay_type_fk` is JSON. The error message indicates that it's not the case...